# Change all commit authors in subversion

Tags: svn

I will perform a subversion migration from the built-in authentication against the central LDAP server using sasl. As part of this change, the usernames will be modified, from `username` to `username@example.com`.

To keep things simple, I'd like to update the authors on all revisions to conform to the same naming scheme. I understand that the author can be changed by allowing revprop changes and changing the `svn:author` property using `svn propset`:

```
svn propset --revprop -r revision_number svn:author your_username
```

However, I'd like to do this using a script, for all revisions.

Is there such a script already available which transforms the `svn:author` property according to a preset pattern for all revisions in a repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In such cases, I would either dump repository, modify and reload the dump, or use scripting to perform whatever changes required in a loop, i.e., if using Bash -

```
for i in {1..999}
do
  svn propset --revprop -r $i svn:author your_username
done
```

Replace 1..999 with actual revisions range to apply to.

Assuming you run the script from where the working copy is, you can get the last revision number within the script as well, i.e.:

```
REV=`svn info | grep Revision: | cut -c11-`
for ((i=0; i<=${REV}; i++))
do
  svn propset --revprop -r $i svn:author your_username
done
```

"svn info" can also be used to retrieve the author of the change:

```
svn info -r revnum | grep 'Last Changed Author:' | cut -c22-
```

Comment: Just a couple of questions: 1. How can I find out the current maximum revision in a script? 2. How can I extract the current author for a revision?

Comment: `Revision:`
    `svn info | grep Revision: | cut -c11-`
`Revision author:`
    `svn info | grep 'Last Changed Author:' | cut -c22-`

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting.  
Revision:  *svn info | grep Revision: | cut -c11-*
Revision author: *svn info | grep 'Last Changed Author:' | cut -c22-*
Markdown somehow doesn't work for me here.

Comment: OK, so svn info gives me the last revision. And I can use `svn propget ...` to get the author for each revision. That's enough to work on, thanks.

Comment: Scripted editing of dump will be more easy and fast solution, IMHO

Comment: @LazyBadger : can you post an answer of that? My repository is pretty small - around 11k revisions, but I'd appreciate a faster conversion.

Comment: `Revision-number: 3
Prop-content-length: 133
Content-length: 133

K 10
svn:author
V 10
lazybadger
K 8
svn:date` just change relevant part of text (all revisions in text-file of dump have the same format). "Find&Replace all" in  text editor may be the easiest way